# How to add snippet of code after the <head> section to all the html files within a folder?

Tags: regex, text, terminal

I have bunch of html files, now I need to insert a snippet of js script to each file. Is there some command line that I can use in terminal to add such snippet to all the files at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's!(?<=</head>)!YOUR_SNIPPET!g' *.html
```

Once you're sure it works, to replace directly in the files, use `perl -i -pe ...` or `perl -i'.bak' -pe ...` to make a back-up.

This is only one of several ways of writing the regex.

Notes

- You can run this from the unix command-line
- `!` is the delimiter (cannot use `/` as it is part of `</head>`)
- The lookbehind `(?<=</head>)` asserts that what immediately precedes the current position is `</head>`
- At this position, we insert `YOUR_SNIPPET`

**Complex Snippet? Declare An Environment Variable**

If the snippet includes apostrophes and `!` chars, you will need to do some escaping or declare the snippet as an environment variable. For instance:

```
env mysnippet="snip'it" perl -pe 's!(?<=</head>)!$ENV{mysnippet}!g' *.html
```

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: thanks!can you explain what does `s!(?<=</head>)!` mean?

Comment: You're welcome! Added these explanations, as well as a reference to `lookbehind`. Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: hi, it does work, but only add the my snippet and print the whole file in terminal, but when I open my file in text editor, the line wasn't there...

Comment: Ah. Sorry about that, I forgot to add it—it's dangerous to give instructions that will replace inside the files. Added it to the answer, basically once you're sure it works, to replace directly in the files, use `perl -i -pe ...` or `perl -i'.bak' -pe ...` to make a back-up.